# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, list, int, append

im new in coding and this is the problematic part of my code:

```
d = [1, 2]
c = 8
list = [5,6,7]
for i in range (len(list)):
        d.append (list[i])
        d = sum(d)*c
```

but there is always an error 'int' object has no attribute 'append' and i dont know whats wrong

Comment: What is this code snippet **supposed** to do?

Comment: Why are you doing `d = sum(d)*c`, especially inside the loop? Do you want `d` to be a list or a number?

Comment: After first iteration, you will have `sum` of `d` and next time `d` will be int value

Answer (score 1):

You're converting your list into an integer in your loop:

```
d = [1, 2] # here d is a list
c = 8
my_list = [5,6,7]
for i in range (len(list)):
        d.append (my_list[i])
        d = sum(d)*c #now you've made it an integer
```

Your loop runs through once, but then fails on the second attempt, because you're treating your now-integer variable `d` as if it were still a list.

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to overwrite python keywords like `list`.